# Lotus Notes : User form over email

Tags: lotus-notes

I am going to organize a team event at my workplace.

I want to call in team nominations for the same.

However, to make the mail interesting, I want to design the mail in such a way that after the usual descriptive content, there should be a form and a button with various fields.

For e.g.

```
Team Name: 
Team Leader:

Member1:
Member2:
Member3:

Submit Button
```

So, the receiver fills these fields with relevant details and on hitting the submit button, I receive a mail back with the nomination details.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible in Lotus Notes and if possible can someone guide me to a simple example somewhere on the web.

Please note that I will not be able to do Notes Scripting. So it there is some inbuild function to create text boxes or user forms similar to button functionality available, then I want to be guided with that.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Consider using Embedded experience. http://goo.gl/SuUld4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and it is quite easy, if you know how to do it.

BUT: You will most probably not be able to do this, as you need the Domino Designer to achieve what you want. If you HAD the Domino Designer, your question would have been more concrete, so I guess you don't have it.

If you want to try it: Get The `Domino Designer` with the right version for your environment, install it and try working with it. 
The most current version of designer can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/).

The `Domino Designer Help` will be a good starting point for you, but without a training or at least somebody who shows you the basics, it will be not possible for you to achieve what you want.

Almost forgot: If your admins did not give you the appropriate rights in the Domino environment, then you will not be able to bring your code to the server, and that means it will be very hard to distribute the form to the users.

Comment: Actually, since he's talking about an email form, all he needs is a local database containing the form.  He can mail directly from that local database, and use the 'Store form in document' option. No deployment on a server will be required. There are ways that stored forms could be blocked, though, and ECL warnings popping up for recipients could be a nuisance as well.